# Intellij Idea проблема с подсказками

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, jsp

Сделал pull проекта на другой компьютер. Теперь Idea подчеркивает названия View в контроллере, которые я разрешаю TilesViewResolver, в jsp не видит модель в springForm(выделяет красным), пропали подсказки сущностей в модели (jsp). Код компилируется и работает. Что отвечает за эти подсказки идеи и как их починить?

Comment: Версии идеи идентичны? Вы не с Community работаете?

Comment: У вас видимо плагина нет на новой idea

Comment: @ Anton Shchyrov, ultimate. Раньше все было нормально в этой же идее. Да. идентичны

Answer (score 0, accepted):

откройте
Project Structure > Facets 
и проверьте что настроен facet для спринга и там указаны используемые контексты

Comment: там два пункта: Spring и Web. Так вот Spring пустой. Пытаюсь добавить через плюсик, выдает ошибку: Cannot create Facet. No suitable modules for Spring facet found.

Comment: попробуйте пустой Spring facet сперва удалить, а потом добавить

Comment: удалил проект и запулил заново. все заработало